# Installed Bunch of New Fonts on Windows 7 - Now None Show Up and System Lags

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, fonts

So I went to install about 5,000 new fonts on my Windows 7 64-bit machine.  It was slow to install them, and I had to leave.  I came back and my PC was shut down, and I had to go through the Windows recovery BS when I powered it on.  Now my computer runs *extremely* slow and any program that has a font menu locks up my whole machine (nothing in Microsoft Office works).  When I go to "Fonts" in the control panel, it says 0 items.  I went through all of the font settings trying to get them to appear.  Nothing helps.  I tried to bring up the Character Map and that froze up my machine too.

How can I fix this?

If I do not get this issue resolved soon, I am wiping this drive and going back to XP (and probably never purchasing another version of Windows again).  I never had any issues with XP and have had nothing but performance problems when switching to Windows 7.  My quad-core intel extreme with 8GB of RAM should never flinch with the kind of work that I do, and something simple like playing a song off an external HD takes up to five seconds on Windows 7.  Unbelievable that I had to pay for this crap!

Comment: `So I went to install about 5,000 new fonts...` there's the problem... Maybe you could use a Live-CD to delete some fonts.

Comment: There could have been a problem during the font installation such as a power failure or hardware failure.  In this case the font's wouldn't have finished installing and rebuilding the cache, this is probably why fonts don't show.  Just revert to your last backup and copy any missing files manually.

Comment: @Bobby That is a ridiculous comment; there is nothing absurd about having 5,000 fonts.  I know designers that have over 30,000 fonts installed on their Macs.  It is not 1995.  Move on if you don't want to help me out.

Comment: Doing a System Restore corrected the problem.  I wonder if it was a corrupt font or if I had a power failure in the middle of installation.  In either case, Windows 7 did a very poor job of handling the situation.

Comment: Josh, please make your solution into an answer and accept it, to close the question. Incidentally, your "It is not 1995" is misguided. Windows font management is not comparable to Mac, and is in fact very poor by comparison. All fonts in the Fonts folder are loaded into memory at startup. That's your problem right there.

Comment: Incidentally, may I suggest separating your issues with fonts, and playing music off an external drive, so that we can address them on SuperUser individually.

Comment: @Josh Stodola: May I suggest you are perhaps asking too much of the poor OS? Indeed, blaming what I assume to be HDD spin-up time, or a failing drive on your OS smacks of ignorance, not a legitimate issue.

Comment: @Phoshi Asking too much?  All I want is a variety of fonts.  And why doesn't this stupid OS handle the situation gracefully instead of locking me out?  I am not ignorant; I demand high performance from my machine.  No excuses.  The problem has nothing to do with my hardware, it is this *flawed* OS that I paid too much money for.  I guess if I want fonts I will switch to OSX.

Comment: @Josh Stodola: You are asking too much insofar as your system clearly failed, most likely not due to your OS, during the installation process, in such a way that broke thing horribly. How you expect any OS to handle things completely outside of it's control...

Comment: @Phoshi I don't know what gives you the impression that what happened was outside the control of the OS.  The OS is what shut down the system!  That's why it attempted to "repair" itself when I booted up.  It was not a power failure; my web server did not flinch.

Comment: @Josh Stodola: You say you left, and when you came back it had restarted? Yes, that's absolutely certainly microsoft's fault. It's probably built into the OS to fail if you try and do anything! System Repair kicks in regardless of why it was shut down, if it detects a problem. I'm not saying win7 is perfect, I'm saying you're putting far too much blame on it. Windows hasn't had a serious limit on fonts since ME, and hasn't BSOD'd through software failure since vista.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Windows can't handle fonts.  I had to do a system restore to get my machine to be functional.  If you want a variety of fonts, you must switch to a different operating system such as Mac OSX.

Comment: windows is able to handle fonts. It just doesn´t work the same way it does on Mac. I found this (http://blog.taragana.com/index.php/archive/how-to-add-fonts-in-windows-7/) about the new "Install fonts" button. But I would sugest you try copying them manually into the fonts folder.

Comment: @Diskilla That is exactly what I did.  It started to install, and when I returned a few hours later the machine had shut down unexpectedly.  I know it was not a power failure because my web server did not flinch.  I tried the same thing several times with the exact same result.  Conclusion: Windows has a font limit that is not enforced.

Answer (score 0):

Windows keep track of installed fonts in registry.

Possible your registry got corrupted when your PC shut down.
Try using a registry cleaner like RegCure and make some fixes.